# MS Exchange integration

Tags: exchange-server

Does there exist a third party component which lets you seamless integrate your calendar application with MS Exchange?

Are there any open source components who do that?

This is about calendar, not mail.

Answer (score 1):

By default, Exchange now use WebDAV to give access to mail & calendar.  You may want to have a look at how the [Evolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Novell_Evolution) mail client does it.